# Есть желание написать клиент серверное приложение чат для Android

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Само приложение хотелось бы создавать на Android studio. Прошу подсказать с технологиями, которые стоит использовать в создании (напр. Spring) и куда разместить БД. Ну и если возможно посоветовать где все это выучить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вопрос очень скоро закроют потому-что причиной будет:

> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на
>   знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос
>   так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо
>   удалите вопрос вовсе.

Тем не менее я постараюсь вас направить на правильный путь (на мой взгляд). Для того чтобы сделать клиент-серверное приложение вам нужно продумать несколько частей этого вопроса: сервер, клиент (телефон в нашем случае) и как они будут взаимодействовать. [Вот](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=336262) есть вводная статья по этому вопросу. Для начала я бы советовал посмотреть в сторону [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). Этот сервис даст вам много преимуществ и вам не нужно будет много чего делать руками самому (если еще нет много опыта). Вот есть инструкция по созданию чата: [ссылка_1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5359-firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat), [ссылка_2](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e) надеюсь поможет в вашем нелегком вопросе.

P.S. В вопросах связанных с программированием лучше не упоминать особо IDE Android Studio типа так:

> Само приложение хотелось бы создавать на Android studio

потому-что ваш вопрос можно перефразировать так:

> я хочу сделать стул используя молоток, какие вы посоветуете мне гвозди
>   при создании этого стула (например винтовой гвоздь и тд.) и куда его
>   потом можно будет поставить.

пример конечно не совсем точно описывает вашу ситуацию но логика должна быть понятна. Вопрос будет закрыт и причина проста - вы задаете вопрос, но не даете людям никакой информации о том что вы уже нашли по вашему вопросу и где у вас возникли сложности. Надеюсь мой ответ поможет вам в освоении Android разработки. Удачи :)